# lua meta-object protocol model: lua-coat vs loose

Tags: lua

There is someone who uses *lua-coat* or *loose* **routinely**?

Which is more mature, stable, bugfree -> "better"?
Is one of them enough mature for the production environment?

- lua-coat - activity none - last updated Nov.2010 - marked as beta
- loose - activity none - last updated in Dec.2008 - ???

Any experience?

*(looking for an answer from someone who has real experience with them :)*

Comment: From what I've seen, most OO libraries for Lua tend to get used only by the people who wrote them (and even then only for a brief experimental period before getting abandoned), because most Lua programmers don't feel the need to inflict an object model upon themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: I have no direct experience with any of those libraries, but I've got some experience creating [my own OOP lib](https://github.com/kikito/middleclass).

Of the two libraries you have proposed, lua-coat seems better. My two main reasons:

- It's got some [fairly recent commits](https://github.com/fperrad/lua-Coat/commits/master)
- It's got automated [tests](https://github.com/fperrad/lua-Coat/tree/62a2e6832e4b1dd48f7a19d52c284805be5869fa/test). IMHO Any serious lib should have them(*), but it's specially important in OOP libs; keeping track of all the things that can go wrong in a refactoring is just impossible without automated testing.

(*) My lib also has tests, mind you. They are just on a [different repo](https://github.com/kikito/middleclass-specs), for now.

Comment: I'm coming from the perl-world, so especially looking for the moose/mouse port to lua. ;) Thanx for the answer.